# Python OpenIDConnect package that works with Azure B2C

Tags: python, azure-ad-b2c

Can someone recommend a Python/Django package to use to login to Azure AD B2C using the b2clogin?

Comment: Did you try  https://mozilla-django-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html